# Sequence of difference

Tags: calculus

I need some help with this question (I'm sorry for my English):

> Let a function $f$ be defined in $\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $|f'(x)|\leq 0.5$. In addition, let a sequence $(a_n)$ be defined by: $a_1 :=1$, $a_{n+1}:=f(a_n)$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
>   Show that ($a_n$) converges.

Thanks all.

Comment: Also, you can apply the banach fixed point theorem

Answer (score 0):

$|a_n- a_{n-1}| = |f(a_{n-1}) - f(a_{n-2})|= |f'(c)||a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}|\le 0.5|a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}| \le 0.5^2|a_{n-2}-a_{n-3}|\le0.5^{n-2}|a_2-a_1|= b\cdot0.5^{n-2}$. From this you can proceed to prove its a Cauchy sequence and convergence follows.